# Working tweet parser but with empty results

Tags: android, twitter

My task is to create app that could get latest tweets from x account.
Here is my code what I've made. However I get result (more than 0) only if i set (as search string) my account name. Otherwise I get nothing. Could someone explain me why? I will appreciate for any help.

```
private ListView lv;
private EditText et;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] values;
private Token token = null;
private Credential c = null;
private UserAccountManager m = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et.setText("twapime");

    doRest();// first run, initialization, first search

}

private void doRest() {
    initAccount();
    initSearching();
}

private void initSearching() {
    ArrayList<String> listax = getSearchResults(et.getText().toString());
    initListViewAdapter(listax);
}

private void initListViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> listax) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listax);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void initAccount() {
    token = new Token("xxxx",
            "xxxx");
    c = new Credential("xxxx",
            "xxxx", token);

    m = UserAccountManager.getInstance(c);
}

private ArrayList<String> getSearchResults(String userTwitter) {
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        if (m.verifyCredential()) {

            SearchDevice sd = SearchDevice.getInstance();
            Query q1 = QueryComposer.from(userTwitter);

            Tweet[] ts = sd.searchTweets(q1);
            System.out.println(ts.length);

            for (int i = 0; i < ts.length; i++) {

                lista.add(ts[i].getString(MetadataSet.TWEET_CONTENT));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LimitExceededException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lista;
}

public void btnSearcher(View w) {//OnClickListener
    initSearching();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it happens when someone block public information data for untrusted user.